# Looping in a fwrite call until the buffer size is written C/C++

Tags: c++, c, io, libcurl

I'm designing a `C++` callback function that writes `size_t size` bytes from a buffer to a file in C++. However, for sanity, I have to check if `fwrite` returns a `errno` such as `EACESS`. The function itself it's an interface between `C` and `C++`. Sure enough, I have a pseudocode (almost real code) written:

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream){
     int nwritten = size;
     while(nwritten > 0){
          int written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE*)stream);
          if(written < 0 && errno == EACESS){
                  // try again
                  written = 0;
          }
          /* check some other errors which may be recoverable 
          nwritten -= written;
     }
```

The function itself is called from [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
```

The point is to make sure `size_t written = size` bytes were written to the file. The reason I'm using a `fwrite` instead any other method is because the function `write_data` is passed as a callback to a method which does a `HTTP` request, makes some file transfering and writes the file content to a local file.
I'm not sure this approach will work. Could you guys tell me if this approach would work, or maybe potential troubles I may have? If there is a better approach ? 
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using C functions in C++ ? File IO is much better handled is C++ imo.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur
The reason I'm using a fwrite instead any other method is because the function write_data is passed as a callback to a method which does a HTTP request, makes some file transfering and writes the file content to a local file

Comment: Why would you _retry_ on `EACCESS`? What condition would change that would allow it to work in the future?

Comment: Replace if by while loop. Put a usleep function if necessary.

Comment: @sarnold 
That's the point of my question is to figure out which `errno` are triable and which aren't. I'm asking the community's help to figure it out.

Comment: Note that `size_t` is usually unsigned, so the test `written < 0` will always be false (your compiler *should* warn you about this; if it doesn't, crank up your warning level).

Comment: @texasbruce
May you post some pseudocode kind of answer, so I could better understand your idea?

Comment: @philippe But why not using `std::ofstream`, for instance? Are you programming in C or C++?

Comment: @betabandido
The callback function is passed to a `C` function. The code is actually an interface between `C/C++`

Comment: If you continue to use `fwrite(3)`, note that it reports its errors via `ferror(3)`; it is pretty sad though, only reporting if a failure occurred. If you really intend to use lower-level routines, a direct `write(2)` might make the most sense, as it _does_ provide you with good error returns.

Comment: Who opens the output file, you or the library?  If it's you, you can very easily use a C++ `fstream` instead of a C `FILE*`.  You just need to cast the `fstream` object's address back and forth from `void*`.

Comment: @sarnold: `fwrite(3)` does not give any error return value like `errno`?

Comment: @philippe: it does not: _`fread()` and `fwrite()` return the number of items successfully read or written (i.e., not the number of characters).  If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero)._ (The portion about `ferror(3)` was actually talking about `fread()`. My mistake there. One more reminder to carefully read manpages. :)

Comment: @AdamRosenfield
I updated my question, now it's possible to see who calls that function.

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite` returns the number of members written, so as you write members you need to advance `ptr`, something like this:

```
size_t done = 0;

while (done < nmemb) {
    size_t written = fwrite((char*)ptr + done * size, size, nmemb - done, (FILE*)stream);
    done += written;
    if (done < nmemb) {
        /* Not all has been written. Some kind of error may have occurred. */
        if (ferror((FILE*)stream)) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference where I can look into, to see the errors fwrite returns?

Comment: It turns out I was wrong. `fwrite` doesn't return an error code. I've edited my answer.

Comment: You need to check the return value to see if it's zero. If it is, you probably want to break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: @cybertextron POSIX defines the errors that can result from fwrite(): https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html . If ferror() returns a non-zero value for the stream, "errno" can then be examined to check which error it was, and the error codes are listed in the definition for fputc(): https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputc.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a robust i/o.
This link and the robust io package might help you : http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/ch10-preview.pdf